# GDAL RasterizeLayer by attribute burns 0 when attribute is null

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-rasterize

I am attempting to burn a shapefile onto a raster with an attribute.  This works really well generally, but where the shapefile feature has null data for the selected attribute (itype_code in the example) a value of 0 is burned. This is problematic as in subsequent processing I cannot identify if the 0 is a 'real' value or simply the Null data.  I would prefer to have it burn in the specified NoData_value.  I read through the documentation and set the nodata value in the options (see code below), but no luck!

Gdl version = '3.5.1'

sample code:

```
source_ds = ogr.Open(str(path))
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()

x_min, y_min = (1296251.0, 5032425.0)
pixelWidth = pixelHeight = 100

cols = 170
rows = 235

target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('{}/temp.tif'.format(self._parent.temp_file_dir), cols,
                                                             rows,
                                                             1,
                                                             gdal.GDT_Float64)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixelWidth, 0, y_min, 0, pixelHeight))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
NoData_value = -999999
band.Fill(NoData_value)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)
band.FlushCache()
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, options=['ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE', 'a_nodata=-999999', 'ATTRIBUTE=itype_code']
```

Comment: Try adding `initValues=-999999` to your `options=[...]` arg.

Comment: Maybe because shapefile does not support null values https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005811.

Comment: @user2856 this made no difference.

Comment: @user30184  Thank  you this explains the behaviour perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

As specified by @user30184 via the link: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005811  shapefieles store the null interger values as 0. There is no way to prevent this, but the best solution to this is simply to implement a user warning when 0 values are written as they may be null or valid.